# The relation between $F^2=f_{\mu\nu}f^{\mu\nu}$ and $H^2=H_{\mu\nu\lambda}H^{\mu\nu\lambda}$

Tags: gravity, field-theory, string-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-gravity

there are two papers https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0411105 and https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9406216. What is relation between the $H^2=H_{\mu\nu\lambda}H^{\mu\nu\lambda}$ in the second paper and $F^2=f_{\mu\nu}f^{\mu\nu}$ in the first paper?

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Do you really expect users to read two full papers to find out what the notation you used here means? To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.